# How should I define a factory class method in a polymorphic class in Python?

Tags: python, polymorphism, python-typing

How should I define a factory class method in a polymorphic class?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='X')
U = TypeVar('U', bound='Y')
V = TypeVar('V', bound='Z')

@dataclass
class X:
    @classmethod
    def factory(cls: type[T], **kwargs: Any) -> T:
        return cls(**kwargs)

@dataclass
class Y(X):
    y: int

    @classmethod
    def factory(cls: type[U], **kwargs: Any) -> U:
        return super().factory(y=0, **kwargs)

@dataclass
class Z(X):
    z: int

    @classmethod
    def factory(cls: type[V], **kwargs: Any) -> V:
        return super().factory(z=0, **kwargs)

class W(Y, Z):
    pass
```

MyPy complains:

```
a.py: note: In class "W":
a.py:30: error: Definition of "factory" in base class "Y" is incompatible with definition in base class "Z"  [misc]
``
```

Comment: Possibly a bug? https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12694

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that each of the factory methods takes a `TypeVar` that has a bound of the class it's present in. It might be that this is needed for the use case, but I wondered if just by replacing these with `Self` the issue could be resolved:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Self

@dataclass
class X:
    @classmethod
    def factory(cls: type[Self], **kwargs: Any) -> Self:
        return cls(**kwargs)

@dataclass
class Y(X):
    y: int

    @classmethod
    def factory(cls: type[Self], **kwargs: Any) -> Self:
        return super().factory(y=0, **kwargs)

@dataclass
class Z(X):
    z: int

    @classmethod
    def factory(cls: type[Self], **kwargs: Any) -> Self:
        return super().factory(z=0, **kwargs)

class W(Y, Z):
    pass
```

Comment: Self unfortunately doesn't fix things.   It's just a new shorthand for what I had.

Comment: Ah that's a shame - the above passes for me in pyright, but I haven't checked mypy. Using `Self` means it matches with the other factory method, because that also returns `Self` (at least that's how it works on my end!)

Comment: I get a lot of errors in PyRight 1.1.350